# Finding real solutions of a system with two variables

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

find all real solutions of $$x^2+y^2+\frac{2xy}{x+y}=1$$ and $$\sqrt{x+y}= x^2-y$$
   I tried using the quadratic formula in first equation with the variable X but messed up the equation.  Also tried supposing $x+y=a$ and $xy=b$ but couldn't break the term $x^2-y$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the second equation, we get $x+y \ge 0$, and from the first equation, we get $x + y \ne 0$, hence $x + y > 0$.

Using the first equation, clear denominators, get all terms on one side, and then factor. This yields
$$(x+y-1)(x^2+x+y+y^2)=0$$
Since $x+y > 0$, it follows that $x^2 + x + y + y^2 > 0$, hence $x+y-1=0$, so $x+y=1$.

This makes the second equation much nicer.

Can you finish it?

Answer (score 1):

squaring the second equation we get $$0=y^2-2x^2y-y-x+x^4$$ this equation can be factorized into $$(x^2-x-y)(x^2+x-y+1)=0$$ the rest is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+\frac{2xy}{x+y} \hspace{4mm}\mbox{ and }\hspace{4mm} g(x,y)=1.$$ 
Then $f$ is a surface in the $3$-dimensional Euclidean space while $g$ is the plane defined by $z=1$.

These two surfaces could intersect at no points, finitely-many points, or infinitely-many points. In your case, they intersect along the line $\color{blue}{r(t)=(t+1,-t)}$, where $\color{blue}{t\in\mathbb{R}}$ and along the circle 
$\color{red}{s(t)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos t-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin t-\frac{1}{2}\right)}$, where $\color{red}{0\leq t\leq 2\pi, t\not=\frac{\pi}{4}}$:

[image: intersection-birds-eye-view]

[image: intersection-side-view]

[image: contour-graph]

Now let 
$$
h(x,y)=\sqrt{x+y} \hspace{4mm}\mbox{ and }\hspace{4mm} k(x,y)=x^2-y.
$$ 
Then 
$h(r(t))=\sqrt{1}=1$ while $k(r(t))=t^2+3t+1$ (note that we are restricting the domain of $h$ and $k$ to those points on the $xy$-plane satisfying the function $f=g$).
Since $h(r(t))=k(r(t))$, we have $0=t^2+3t$, or $0=t(t+3)$. This implies $t=0$ or $t=-3$. 
So real solutions to the two functions are: 
$$
\color{green}{\boxed{r(0)=(1,0)} \hspace{4mm} \mbox{ and }\hspace{4mm} 
\color{green}{\boxed{r(-3)=(-2,3)}}}. 
$$
We also need to check for which $t$ do we have the equality $h(s(t))= k(s(t))$. We obtain the real solution to $h(s(t))= k(s(t))$ when $t=\frac{\pi}{4}$. 
However, $\frac{\pi}{4}$ is not in the domain of $s$, i.e., $s\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)=(0,0)$, but $f(0,0)$ is undefined.

Thus we conclude that there are only two real solutions, which are in the above boxes.

---

Note: we obtain the two parametrizations from the function $x^2+y^2+\frac{2xy}{x+y}=1$ in the following way. Clear the denominator, expand, move all terms to one side, and factor to obtain
$$
(y+x-1)(x^2+x+y^2+y)=0. 
$$
This means $y+x-1=0$ or $x^2+x+y^2+y=0$. The first equation is the line $\color{blue}{y=-x+1}$ and the second equation is an equation of a circle (which we obtain by completing the square): 
$$
\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 -\frac{1}{4} + \left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 -\frac{1}{4} =0 
\mbox{ implies } 
\color{red}{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 =\frac{1}{2}}.
$$
Note that we delete the point on the circle which lies along the line $x+y=0$.